# TailwindCSS: Auto Hight of grid cols

Tags: html, css, grid, tailwind-css

I am wondering why auto height of grid columns is not working in tailwindcss:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<div class="grid grid-cols-3 gap-4">
    <div class="bg-blue-100" style="height: auto!important">test</div>
    <div class="bg-blue-100 h-auto">test</div>
    <div class="bg-blue-100">test<br />test</div>
</div>
```

It would work, if I'd set `h-xxx` but I want auto height. All cols should have a height based on it's content not on the highest col.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default value of align-items is `normal`, which acts similar to `stretch` in a grid container. You need to set `align-items:base-line` instead. (`items-baseline` in tailwind, or other aligning value such as `center` depending on your need.)

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<div class="grid grid-cols-3 gap-4 items-baseline">
  <div class="bg-blue-100">test</div>
  <div class="bg-blue-100">test</div>
  <div class="bg-blue-100">test<br />test</div>
</div>
```

As for why `height:auto` is not working, when `align-items:stretch` is set, each items acts [as defined for](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-align/#valdef-align-self-stretch) `justify-self:stretch`. Hence, as per [spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-align/#valdef-justify-self-stretch) setting height to auto doesn't make it fits the content's height.

> When the box’s computed width/height (as appropriate to the axis) **is auto** and neither of its margins (in the appropriate axis) are auto, sets the box’s used size to the length necessary to make its outer size as close to filling the alignment container as possible while still respecting the constraints imposed by min-height/min-width/max-height/max-width.

Because of this, setting `h-fit` on each items would work as well.